# awk (or sed, or something else) - reference match on a previous line and add a line

Tags: awk

I want to add a procedure call to the first line of every single stored procedure in a MySQL database (more than 50 stored procedures) that passes the executing routine's name to the new call.

There's no easy way to do this from within MySQL that I can work out, so I thought I'd give it a go exporting the routines using MySQLdump, editing the file with awk/sed/something and then re-creating the SPs. It's proved trickier than I expected.

This involves finding the function name from the `CREATE ... PROCEDURE` line, and then adding the `CALL NewFunc(currentFuncName)` line after the next `BEGIN` statement. Importantly, the next BEGIN statement isn't always the same number of lines after the CREATE.

I'm part-way there, I just can't work out how to tie up the two bits. I can get the function name with this:

```
awk '/CREATE.*PROCEDURE/ {gsub(/^.*PROCEDURE `|`\(.*$/,"");print "call newFuncHere(" $1 ");"}'
```

How do I get awk to add the result of this *after* the next BEGIN statement?

Example source:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`blah@%` PROCEDURE `theProcedure`(`param1` BIGINT(21) UNSIGNED,
theExisting BIGINT(21) UNSIGNED,
INOUT `myStatus` VARCHAR(255) )
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    DECLARE blah VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT NULL;
```

Example output:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`blah@%` PROCEDURE `theProcedure`(`param1` BIGINT(21) UNSIGNED,
theExisting BIGINT(21) UNSIGNED,
INOUT `myStatus` VARCHAR(255) )
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    CALL newFuncHere(theProcedure);
    DECLARE blah VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT NULL;
```

Indentation is not relevant - just shown for example

---

Edited to add, forgot about the requirement that DECLARE statements must come first, so this is what I've ended up with...

```
# Initialise variables
BEGIN { seen=0; beginCount=-1; createCount=-1; done=0; }

# Ignore blank lines but still print them out
/^$|^\t$/ { print $0 ; next ;}

# If matches CREATE.*PROCEDURE|FUNCTION - increase createCount and set name of function/beginCount variables
/^CREATE/{createCount++} ($5~/PROCEDURE/ || $5~/FUNCTION/)  { name=$6 ; beginCount=-1 }

# If BEGIN is found - increase beginCount - this is to count the depth of BEGIN statements
/BEGIN/ {beginCount++}

# Increment seen variable if DECLARE is in this line
/DECLARE/{seen++}

# If beginCounter = 0, we're at BEGIN level 0 (starts at -1) and if done is not set we've not yet done anything. A
# create depth of 0 (starts at -1), and we've seen at least one DECLARE line,
# if this line does NOT contain DECLARE, add the new line we want, followed
# by a newline and the current line. Reset some variables.
!done && !beginCount && !createCount && seen && !/DECLARE/{ print "CALL newFunction('" name "');" ORS $0 ; seen=0;count++; done=1 ; next;}

#{print createCount seen beginCount done}

# If END is seen and we're inside a nested BEGIN statement, decrement beginCount
# print out the line and skip to the next line
/END.*;/ && beginCount {beginCount--; print $0 ; next ;}

# If END is seen and we're at the top level, reset some counters
/END.*;/ && !beginCount {createCount=-1 ; beginCount=-1 ; seen=0; done=0; }

# print out the line
{ print $0 ;}
```

It's not perfect, it needs work to handle END IF statements, doesn't handle situations where the DECLARE statement covers multiple lines and there's a few other situations it doesn't work, and there's some redundant stuff in there from previous experiments - but it's good enough for my needs right now.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Yes it’s backticks and I’ve updated with expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- current procedure name is field #4 in a backtick-delimited line
- the new line is to be indented the same as the `BEGIN` plus 3 more characters (eg, total of 4 characters for the example)

Sample input:

```
$ cat ddl.sql
CREATE DEFINER=`blah@%` PROCEDURE `theProcedure`(`param1` BIGINT(21) UNSIGNED,
theExisting BIGINT(21) UNSIGNED,
INOUT `myStatus` VARCHAR(255) )
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    DECLARE blah VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT NULL;
    BEGIN
    ....
 ....
..
BEGIN
BEGIN
END
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -F'`' '
procname && /BEGIN/ { print
                      n=index($0,"BEGIN")+3                                  # find indentation of "BEGIN" and +3
                      printf "%*scall newFuncHere(%s);\n", n, "", procname   # indent by "n" spaces
                      procname=""
                      next
                    }
/CREATE.*PROCEDURE/ { procname=$4 }
1
' ddl.sql
```

This generates:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`blah@%` PROCEDURE `theProcedure`(`param1` BIGINT(21) UNSIGNED,
theExisting BIGINT(21) UNSIGNED,
INOUT `myStatus` VARCHAR(255) )
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    call newFuncHere(theProcedure);
    DECLARE blah VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT NULL;
    BEGIN
    ....
 ....
..
BEGIN
BEGIN
END
```

Comment: Excellent, this has done the job for me perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation on @markp-fuso's answer that relies on `PROCEDURE` appearing as the 3rd field in the line containing the function name as the 4th field, and then relies on `BEGIN` appearing at the beginning of the line after which you want to insert the new function call could be:

```
awk -F'`' '
    /^CREATE/ && $3~/PROCEDURE/  { name=$4 }
    /^BEGIN/  { print $0 ORS "    CALL newFuncHere(" name ");"; next }
              1
' file
```

Above there are 3-Rules:

- The first conditioned upon `/^CREATE/ && $3~/PROCEDURE/` simply saves the function name as `name`;
- The second conditioned upon `/^BEGIN/` simply outputs the current record and the new function call and skips to the next record (**note:** this presumes there will always be a function name before each `BEGIN` line -- if not, set and unset name and add `name` as a condition);
- The final rule `1` is simply shorthand for the default `print` command that outputs the current record unchanged.

**Example Use/Output**

With your sample data in the file `file`, you could simply copy/middle-mouse paste the above into an xterm with `file` in the present working directory and receive:

```
$ awk -F'`' '
>     /^CREATE/ && $3~/PROCEDURE/  { name=$4 }
>     /^BEGIN/  { print $0 ORS "    CALL newFuncHere(" name ");"; next }
>               1
> ' f
CREATE DEFINER=`blah@%` PROCEDURE `theProcedure`(`param1` BIGINT(21) UNSIGNED,
theExisting BIGINT(21) UNSIGNED,
INOUT `myStatus` VARCHAR(255) )
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    CALL newFuncHere(theProcedure);
    DECLARE blah VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT NULL;
```

This just simplifies the syntax a bit.

Comment: fwiw, it isn't uncommon for SQL code/scripts to contain multiple `BEGIN` statements and while they are typically nested via increasing indents there's nothing to keep multiple `BEGIN`s starting in the first column (or no `BEGIN`s starting in column #1); it's also possiible (don't know if this applies to OPs situation) that multiple objects (procedures, triggers, queries, etc) can exist in the input file, each with a `BEGIN` (likely starting in column #1); OP kinda hints at this ... *after the next `BEGIN` statement*; net result is you may want to further limit when the `call ...` line is added

Comment: I wondered about that and added the additional note that if the sequence wasn't constant, then setting and unsetting `name` and adding that as a condition would be needed. (which explains what you did with `procname`) Thanks.

Comment: I've done something based on this but using counters being incremented and decremented on BEGIN and END statements to keep track of which BEGIN I'm at. It's not pretty but it works.